Type is assignable to the constraint of type, but could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
i have a code like this:
type ItemWithId = { id: string }

type Column<TData extends ItemWithId> = {
    label: string
    sortable?: boolean
    render: (item: TData, items: TData[]) => ReactNode
}

type ColumnsBuilder<TData extends ItemWithId> = {
    build: (options: Column<TData>) => Column<TData>
}

type ContextValue<TData extends ItemWithId> = {
    columns: Column<TData>[]
    items: TData[]
}

const DataListContext = createContext<ContextValue<ItemWithId> | undefined>(undefined)

type RootProperties<TData extends ItemWithId> = PropsWithChildren<{
    items: TData[]
    getColumns: (builder: ColumnsBuilder<TData>) => Column<TData>[]
}>

export function Root<TData extends ItemWithId>(properties: RootProperties<TData>) {
    const { items, getColumns, children } = properties

    const columns = useMemo(() => {
        return getColumns({
            build(options: Column<TData>) {
                const { sortable = false, ...restOptions } = options

                return {
                    ...restOptions,
                    sortable,
                }
            },
        })
    }, [getColumns])

    const value = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            columns,
            items,
        }
    }, [columns, items])

    return <DataListContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</DataListContext.Provider>
}

On statement <DataListContext.Provider value={value} i get an error:
Type '{ columns: Column<TData>[]; items: TData[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ContextValue<ItemWithId>'.
  Types of property 'columns' are incompatible.
    Type 'Column<TData>[]' is not assignable to type 'Column<ItemWithId>[]'.
      Type 'Column<TData>' is not assignable to type 'Column<ItemWithId>'.
        Type 'ItemWithId' is not assignable to type 'TData'.
          'ItemWithId' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TData', but 'TData' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ItemWithId'.

why it happened and how to fix this?
Playground

The error arises because TypeScript's type system is invariant by default, meaning it does not allow the assignment of types that are not the same. In your case, ContextValue<ItemWithId> and ContextValue<TData> are considered different types, even though TData extends ItemWithId.
To resolve this issue, you need to find a way of telling the compiler that both value and DataListContext share the same type.
One of the ideas is to extract the logic of building a context value to a reusable generic hook. Then, create a dedicated Root for each ContextValue type. Since you didn't mention the usage of Root in your project, I can't tell how significant it is to have a single function. From the implementation details, it makes sense, because the Context you provide will always narrow down to the generic type of the ContextValue you provide (ContextValue<ItemWithId> in your case) See this playground (1).
If that doesn't suit your implementation strategy, please share more details about the usage of Root. You might want to rethink your architecture.
EDIT:
It's also possible to have one Root generic component. You need to combine it with checking for a particular RootProperties type using Typescript's type predicate. See this playground (2).
